# How to check that a generated string contains at least one letter

Tags: php

How to check tgat a generated string contains at least one letter using php.

Can someone help me?

Comment: you might wanna google some more: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: What do you mean when you say "one alphabet"?

Comment: I dont want a string conatins only numbers like '1234' , it should contains atleast one alphabet like '123a'..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use preg_match with very simple Regex

try:

```
$string = "3456525675612765";

$pattern = '/[A-Za-z]/';
preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
if (!$matches)
{
    print "no letters";
}
```

Comment: I used this.. preg_match("/[.?*a-zA-Z]/",$str).. but its not showing correct answer..

Comment: No problem, next time you'll help me ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check for any letter, not just letters from the English alphabet, you should use:

```
preg_match('/\p{L}/', $string);
```

This regular expression matches a string containing any kind of letter from any language.